# How to disable JavaScript debugging in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have been trying very hard to debug with VS2015 but there is this javascript that keeps getting on the way.
Have turned off the Just-In-Time script but still it is running thru the javascript without debugging on the breakpoint that I have set.
So fat, I only see the question asked on VS2013.
Please help.
Tks.

Answer (score 6):

It's been three years but maybe it helps someone;
Go to Tools / Options / Debugging / General
Then uncheck the Enable Javascript Debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome, Edge and IE)

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for the same and I found [this workaround](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/greggm/2009/04/06/disabling-script-debugging-in-vs-2008-ie8/) - Seems if you debug Silverlight then it disables JS debugging.

IMO - I prefer to debug in the browser with F12 dev tools

Answer (score 0):

The only way i am able to do it it's when you enable "silverlight" debugging, but you need the silverlight runtime, instead that you will always get an "error" when start the solution in debugging mode, but it will work.